# Android Service stop by itself?

Tags: android, service, timer, countdowntimer

I am trying to create my own clock or timer using android **CountdownTimer**. So , i want that , even if , i closed my application , the android service should run and which will update my clock. So when i will be opening my application , i can see the latest time.

My code is working fine , but sometime after long time , the service stop by itself. So , the timer stops and i am seeing time in the application.

So , please let me know , how to restrict the service to stop by itself.

Comment: is the following answer worked for you?

Comment: Yes i got some hint. But how startForeground will handle the memory low issue. but may which tablet is i am using , that is brand new one how can it possible to have memory low issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's achievable through START_REDELIVER_INTENT,START_STICKY

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    // START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus.

But you can use startForeground(int, Notification). [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).

Here you can find a lot of useful information:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html